# testing applicationContext: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, applicationcontext

So I have this helper class for getting the application context:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

and its unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration()
public class ApplicationContextProviderTest {

    @Test
    public void getApplicationContextInstance(){
        assertNotNull(ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

with the following resource file (same package with test class):
*ApplicationContextProviderTest-context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:map id="contextProperties" />

    <bean id="applicationContextProvider"
          class="com.ideyatech.morphlynx.application.ApplicationContextProvider" />
</beans>
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: class com.ideyatech.morphlynx.application.listener.ApplicationContextProviderTest
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:169)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:93)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:305)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:367)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:362)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:207)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:622)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;ZZ)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils$4.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:96)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils$4.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:93)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:198)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:165)
    ... 30 more
```

- How can I fix this? *I'm guessing that this is caused by wrong versioning of spring core*
- Any better way to test **ApplicationContextProvider**?

Thanks!

Comment: _I'm guessing that this is caused by wrong versioning of spring core_ Yes. Show us the versions you are using.

Comment: The project uses core-3.0.5.RELEASE, but then I was getting an error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils".

I added core-4.0.5.RELEASE to the classpath, that was when I got the error in my post.

Comment: What about the other Spring libs?

Comment: most are also 3.0.5.RELEASE or 3.X.X.RELEASE

Comment: Don't mix. Have them all be the same.

Comment: So I won't use core4.0.5.RELEASE? 
How should I test then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I should use **spring-test-3.0.5**, like the version of my other spring jars.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same error while testing Spring Security 4.0.0.M1. 
With 3.2.4.RELEASE there is no trouble.

Try it with 3.2.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error message when dealing with Apache Tomcat and webapps.
A jar/class could be in the classpath when Apache Tomcat is being launched AND also be included within the webapp classes/lib folder.

The solution in this case is remove the duplicate class/jar.